# Parameter index out of range when trying to retrieve the return value of a stored function

Tags: mysql, jdbc, return-value, sqlexception, callable-statement

I have a function that takes a few parameters and is generating a unique varchar id to be returned to the application.  When I call the function from my java application it executes (the data is inserted), but when I try to retrieve the outparam it throws SQL exception

Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0).

java code:

```
String sql = "{?=call mytable.myFunction (?,?,?,?,?)}";
CallableStatement tmt = sqlConn.prepareCall(sql);
         tmt.registerOutParameter(1, Types.VARCHAR);
         tmt.setString(2, firstName);
         tmt.setString(3, lastName);
         tmt.setDate(4, new java.sql.Date(dob.getTime()));
         tmt.setString(5, null);
         tmt.setString(6, null);

         tmt.execute();

         String accountNumber = tmt.getString(1);
```

I'm using Navicat to work with MySQL, and the procedure executes in Navicat and shows the correct return value.  However, when I call tmt.getString(1) from java app, it throws the above exception.

Please, help.
Thank you.

Comment: Post the CREATE code for the function.  Maybe it's not defined properly.